# facebook graph api: get status link from id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

if you search for "spiegel.de" via graph api:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=spiegel&type=post&locale=de_DE`

the results do not contain status urls.

how to generate the facebook status urls from graph api result?

Answer (score 3):

Having the `status id`, which has the following structure:

```
<userid>_<statusid>
```

If you directly append this with, `facebook.com`, you will have something like this:

```
http://facebook.com/<userid>_<statusid>
```

For eg. if you have an ID `411158702281601_130747537082452`, you can directly append this as,

http://facebook.com/411158702281601_130747537082452

Which will be the link to the status.

Answer (score 1):

each result in the resultset contains an unique id like

`142064272527925_534931533191604`

this `id` is structured like

`<userid>_<postid>`.

just build the status urls as followed:

`https://www.facebook.com/<userid>/posts/<postid>`

e.g.

`https://www.facebook.com/142064272527925/posts/534931533191604`